# SQL query select rows less than or equal to the (max - min) of an existing column

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table named ages containing one column called age that just contains rows of age integers.

I want to find rows that are less than or equal to the (MAX(age) - MIN(age)).

The approach I first took was doing

`SELECT * FROM ages WHERE age <= MAX(age) - MIN(age)` which didn't work because we can't use aggregate in the where clause.

IS there anyway one could solve this problem using a sql query?

Comment: What about [`HAVING`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php)? Would it work for you?

Comment: You might want to join the table with itself. Group the first by age to get the max and min and then join to select the rows that meet the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Aggregate the table to find maximum, minimum, and difference.
2. Then compare with your rows.

The query consists of a main query and a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM ages WHERE age <= (SELECT MAX(age) - MIN(age) FROM ages);
```

Comment: works! thank you so much. I was trying to use a variety of methods like CASE and ANY, but I think yours is much more efficient